# How to calculate time difference between the rows groupby rowname and extract only the most recent ones?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, group-by

I want to calculate the number of days between 2 rows with a grouby function and extract only 1 row with the latest date. I need not want all the rows with the same row value instead want the one which is more recent with the number of days as new column.

```
In [37]: df 
Out[37]:
  id                time
0  A 2016-11-25 16:32:17
1  A 2016-11-27 16:36:04
2  A 2016-11-29 16:35:29
3  B 2016-11-25 16:35:24
4  B 2016-11-28 16:35:46
```

I want the output as

```
   id     no of days
0   A     4(approx)
1   B     3(approx)
```

So what i want is only the column 2 with id A which has the most recent change in time and date and omit rest of rows.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.groupby('id').time.apply(lambda x : (x.max()-x.min()).days)
Out[1186]: 
id
A    4
B    3
Name: time, dtype: int64
```